# PHP connection login

Tags: php

I have a PHP login connected to a table (scholarly_accounts)

Login Form:

```
    <title>Scholarly LMS Login</title>
    <body>
    <?php
    //Start session
    session_start();    
    //Unset the variables stored in session
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']);
    ?>
    </body>
    <form name="loginform" action="login_exec.php" method="post">
    <table width="309" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <!--the code bellow is used to display the message of the input validation-->
         <?php
            if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
            echo '<ul class="err">';
            foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
                echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
                }
            echo '</ul>';
            unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
            }
        ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="116"><div align="right">Username</div></td>
    <td width="177"><input name="username" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Password</div></td>
    <td><input name="password" type="password" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right"></div></td>
    <td><input name="" type="submit" value="login" /></td>
  </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Login_exec.php:

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('connection.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $username = clean($_POST['username']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    //Input Validations
    if($username == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM scholarly_accounts WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: dashboard.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
            $errflag = true;
            if($errflag) {
                $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                session_write_close();
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

How do I then store the person's username that just logged in and display the username and correlating data on a separate page?

ie: Display "Hello, firstname! Your next class is ______"

Comment: If login is going to successful then save the record of that user in an session and use happily on other pages. at the time of log out destroy that session.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post details from `login_exec.php`. As was mentioned, if you set a `$_SESSION` variable, you can then use it on other PHP Pages.

Comment: @Twisty Just uploaded login_exec.php

Comment: Ok, what do you see/get when `dashboard.php` loads?

Comment: **Note:** Never, ever suppress your functions (the `@` in front of `trim()`). Solve your programming issues, don't mask them.

Comment: side note, mysql_ functions are deprecated. Switch to mysqli or PDO and use prepared statements. That clean() function is like 20 years old by this point.

Comment: Figured it out myself. Thanks!

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a reckless lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-i

Answer (score 1):

Use session for that, also on another page u need to use session_start to make data visible on another page

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']=$member['username'];
```

To show username

```
echo "<h3>user: ".$_SESSION['username']."</h3>";
```

to logout u can use session destroy object